# Dependency property not set in OnOk

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

If I edit a text in a TextBox and then press enter in order to fire the Click event of the default key, I don't get the correct value in the Click handler.

How can I get this value in my handler?

Here is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.DefaultKeyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DefaultKeyWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding test}" />
    <Button Click="OnOk" IsDefault="True">OK</Button>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And here my code behind:

```
    public partial class DefaultKeyWindow : Window
{
    public string test
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(testProperty); }
        set { SetValue(testProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for test.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty testProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("test", typeof(string), typeof(DefaultKeyWindow), new PropertyMetadata("initial value"));


    public DefaultKeyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void OnOk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Value of test is " + test);
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a `TextBox` won't update the `Binding` until it loses focus. You can easily get around this by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: This works thank you, but this will fire PropertyChanged on every key pressed. Why doesn't the TextBox loose it's focus? When enter activates the default button I think it should also set new focus.

Comment: Yes, it will update on every key press. You can easily tell if the focus has changed to your `Button`. Since the caret still in the `TextBox`, it hasn't lost focus.